# Is it possible to set weblimits per application

Tags: iis-7.5

I need to set Application Host webLimits for my site, however I have two applications running under one site and they both need different settings.

e.g.

```
Server
   +- Root Site      - Site 1 - Settings 1 below
      -- page
      -- page
      +- Admin site  - Site 2 - Settings 2 below
         -- page
```

Settings 1

```
<configuration>
   <system.applicationHost>
      <webLimits connectionTimeout="00:01:00"
         headerWaitTimeout="00:00:30"
         minBytesPerSecond="500"
      />
   </system.applicationHost>
</configuration>
```

Settings 2

```
<configuration>
   <system.applicationHost>
      <webLimits connectionTimeout="00:01:00"
         headerWaitTimeout="00:05:00"
         minBytesPerSecond="5000"
      />
   </system.applicationHost>
</configuration>
```

As I understand it, the settings are at a server level - is there any way I can link them to a specific application, or application pool?

Answer (score -2):

You need to run two applications from two application instances, e.g. virtual folders, as these settings apply to them, and not the folder of the app, but the virtual folder.

Comment: The settings are server specific - I want to know if there is any restriction you can add.  See http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost